# Knockout template not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a viewModel which contains an observable `folder` object (undefined on initialization)

I have a `foreach` template that should display the files of the folder, which is not working.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hV89w/2/)

Html

```
<div data-bind="template: { if: currentFolder(), foreach: currentFolder.files }">
    <div style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #f0f0f0">
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="button">Set current folder</button>
```

Javascript

```
var viewModel = {
    currentFolder: ko.observable()
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

document.getElementById('button').onclick = addCurrentFolder;

function addCurrentFolder() {
    var folder = {
        files: [ "File 1", "File 2", "File 3" ]
    };
    viewModel.currentFolder(folder);

    // does nothing

    console.log(viewModel.currentFolder());
};
```

Comment: Try and execute your currentFolder observable in the foreach `foreach: currentFolder().files`

Comment: Yes, this works. However, i need to initialize currentFolder with an empty object, otherwise i get an error: `currentFolder: ko.observable({})`. Add your comment as answer to mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and execute your currentFolder observable in the foreach

```
foreach: currentFolder().files
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `foreach` binding needs to be `foreach: currentFolder().files` since `currentFolder` is an observable containing an object and as such it needs to be invoked in order to "unwrap" its contents.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do data-bind with either observable or observableArray. I have created fiddle for you.

And your html code should be as follows,

```
<div data-bind="foreach: currentFolder">
    <div style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #f0f0f0">
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since I am binding "currentFolder" with "foreach", knockout is expecting currentFolder as an observableArray. So you have to change view model as follows,

```
var viewModel = {
    currentFolder: ko.observableArray()
};
```

And then push values to observable array as follows,

```
viewModel.currentFolder.pushAll([ "File 1", "File 2", "File 3" ])
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/hV89w/12/

EDIT:

You have to change "currentFolder" as an observableArray. Right now, currentFolder().files can render what you want. However, This is not recommended. Because, It wont capture file level changes. I mean, the UI wont update, on doing `currentFolder().files.push("File N")`.

And if you want to update UI, then you have to do like as follows,

```
var folder = currentFolder();
folder.files.push("File N");
viewModel.currentFolder(folder);
```

This approach is make all UI refresh. I mean, this will refresh whole UI in following HTML. This process is consider as costlier.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: currentFolder">
    <div style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #f0f0f0">
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the folder will have other arrays inside, i can't make it as an observable array

Comment: @RaraituL, I have explained some drawbacks in current approach.